# Bootstrap 4 - Modal Form fechar apenas no botão

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

Tenho um modal que é exibido no carregamento da pagina com alguns campos, onde eu preciso que ele seja fechado apena no botão sair, porem se eu acionar o click fora do modal ele fecha. Estou utilizando bootstrap 4 com Angular 7.

Alguém sabe se existe componenet para esse caso ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenterAntenas2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterAntenasTitle"
    aria-hidden="true">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta incluir o atributo `data-backdrop="static"` na modal:

```
           ↓
<div data-backdrop="static" class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenterAntenas2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterAntenasTitle"
    aria-hidden="true">
...
</div>
```

Segundo a [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#options), essa opção desabilita o fechamento da modal ao clicar no layer transparente:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Abrir modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Sam. Atendeu perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

resolvi da seguinte forma.

Utilizando a chamada pelo o botão.

```
 <a data-controls-modal="your_div_id"
   data-backdrop="static"
   data-keyboard="false"
   href="#">
```

Ou

No carregamento a pagina.

```
$('#myModal').modal({
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: false
});
```

Valeu pessoal.